# Prove an analytic function is identically $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in a region containing $0$. If $|f(1/n)|<e^{-n}$ for $n>0$, prove that $f$ is identically $0$.

My attempt: Write $f(z)=z^kg(z)$. Then
$$|f(1/n)|=|(1/n^k)g(1/n)|<e^{-n}$$
So
$$|g(1/n)|<\frac{n^k}{e^n}\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$.
I'm not sure if this helps though.

Edit:

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$. So let $k$ be the order of the zero at $f(0)$. If $f$ is nonconstant, then $f(z)=z^kg(z)$, where $g(0)\ne0$. Follow the expression above, to get
$$|g(1/n)|<\frac{n^k}{e^n}\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$. But then $g(0)=0$ as well, by continuity. Contradiction, therefore such $g$ cannot exist, therefore $f$ is constant, therefore $f$ is identically 0.

Comment: Your idea is good. From the assumption we can conclude that $f(0)=0$ (why?). Now assume the order of the zero $z=0$ is $k\in\mathbb N$. Then you can find an analytic function $g$ with $g(0)\neq0$ and $f(z)=z^k g(z)$ in a neighbourhood of 0. Now use your idea to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Ok so $f(0)=0$ since $f$ is analytic and $f\to0$ as $1/n\to0$. Then $g(0)\ne0$ by the way it is defined. But now we used what I derived to see that $g(0)$ must also be $0$ in a similar way we said $f(0)=0$. That is, $g\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. This is the contradiction.

Comment: To derive that $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$ you only need continuity. But yes, that's the idea :)